# Get property of local store javascript file in sencha touch

Tags: javascript, html, sencha-touch, store

I want to get the success property from my users.json. How can I access it? This code is from [here](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store).

```
{
    "success": true,
    "users": [
        {
            "firstName": "Tommy",
            "lastName": "Maintz",
            "age": 24,
            "eyeColor": "green"
        },
        {
            "firstName": "Aaron",
            "lastName": "Conran",
            "age": 26,
            "eyeColor": "blue"
        },
        {
            "firstName": "Jamie",
            "lastName": "Avins",
            "age": 37,
            "eyeColor": "brown"
        }
    ]
}
```

Code:

```
// Set up a model to use in our Store
Ext.define("User", {
    extend: "Ext.data.Model",
    config: {
        fields: [
            {name: "firstName", type: "string"},
            {name: "lastName",  type: "string"},
            {name: "age",       type: "int"},
            {name: "eyeColor",  type: "string"}
        ]
    }
});

var myStore = Ext.create("Ext.data.Store", {
    model: "User",
    proxy: {
        type: "ajax",
        url : "/users.json",
        reader: {
            type: "json",
            rootProperty: "users"
        }
    },
    autoLoad: true
});

Ext.create("Ext.List", {
    fullscreen: true,
    store: myStore,
    itemTpl: "{lastName}, {firstName} ({age})"
});
```

Comment: Did you get any error ?

Comment: No, this is working. But how can I access the success property? I tried to find it in the Object from my store, but I can not find anything.

Comment: why didn't you set successProperty in proxy reader ? and if you want to handle exception using success.. then i think you need to look at following links [link1] (http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?129380-how-i-can-to-use-successProperty-for-json-response) [link2] (http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?135143-RESTful-Model-How-to-indicate-that-the-PUT-operation-failed) [link3] (http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?126656-Where-to-trap-Store-Proxy-exception/page2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the success property with

```
var success = myStore._proxy._reader.rawData.success;
```